# Why is my spread operator returning a SyntaxError: Unexpected Token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code is telling me that my spread operator that I use in the setState in my onInputBlur function. Is this syntax incorrect? I'm using the same syntax in other components and having no issues. Is it a simple syntax problem, or do you suspect that it has to do with a bigger issue?

Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';

class StateSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      inputCSS: this.props.styles.input || {}
    }


    this.onInputBlur = this.onInputBlur.bind(this)
  }

  onInputBlur = (event) => {
    let choice = event.target.value
    const { styles } = this.props

    if(choice){
      return this.setState(state=> {
        inputCSS: {
          ...state.inputCSS,
          border: '1px solid green'
        }
      })
    } else {
      return this.setState(state=> {
        inputCSS: {
          ...state.inputCSS,
          border: '1px solid red'
        }
      })
    }

  }

  render() {
    const { styles } = this.props
    return (
       <div style={styles.formInput}>
        <select id="state" name="state" onChange={this.props.saveInputVal} onBlur={this.onInputBlur} style={this.state.inputCSS}>
      <option value disabled selected>State</option>
      {Object.keys(States).map((key) => {
        return ( <option key={key} value={key}>{States[key]}</option> )
      })}
    </select>
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not with spread syntax. If you want to return an object from `arrow` function, then you have to wrap that in `()` brackets.

```
  return this.setState(state=> ({
    inputCSS: {
      ...state.inputCSS,
      border: '1px solid green'
    }
  }))
```

Comment: Otherwise, there is an ambiguity with the braces that open the function scope.